# How to group files by file types in bash

Tags: bash

I got a bunch of recovered files that do not have the appropriate extension. How can I group them into separate directories based on the file type? (e.g. pdf in one directory, images in another...)

I tried `file * | grep -ie [myKeyword]`, but I don't know how to extract the file names from the output and pass it to `mv`. Also looked into `find`, but as far as I can tell it can only distinguish between directory, link, and file, not specific file types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`file` can be piped to `awk` to return only the file type that'll be used to setup the directories:

```
for i in *; do
    dir=$(file "$i" | awk -F ': |, ' '{print $2}');
    if [[ "$i" != "directory" ]]; then
        mkdir -p "${dir%% *}"
        mv "$i" "${dir%% *}/$i"
    fi
done
```

The basic idea is to setup a variable (`$dir`) using the result of `file` piped to `awk` then create the appropriate directories and move the files into them. Using `: |,` equates to the delimiter being colon + space (`:`) or (`|`)  comma (`,`) + space.

To do a *dry run* first use:

```
for i in *; do
    dir=$(file "$i" | awk -F ': |, ' '{print $2}')
    if [[ "$i" != "directory" ]]; then
        echo "${dir%% *}"
        echo "$i" "${dir%% *}/$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: @mklement0: Thank you! It's not perfect by all means; it could use some fine tuning in regards to unknown file types (eg. it will make a directory named "cannot" if it's unknown) — so I might put that in there or have it replace the name with "unknown". The surprising part about the filetypes returned was that for `.dmg` files (they come back as `VAX`), which seems unusual.

Comment: No need for `awk` to take filename out of `file` output -- `file -b` would do.

Comment: @codeforester: I'm only using the first word of the returned string though (eg. `Fasttracker II module sound data Title: "atari.mod"` becomes `Fasttracker`). I believe using `-b` option only eliminates the filename from the output.

Comment: Got, it.  Your logic makes sense.

Comment: You could simplify to `file -b "$i" | awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $1}'`, however.

Comment: There's no reason to make this a one-liner, so I indented the code properly over multiple lines.  You can still paste it at the prompt in one go if you like.  The one-liner would only obscure things IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [l'L'l](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42966034/45375) for the type-grouping idea.

In the end this answer turned out to be just a variation of [their helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42966034/45375), although perhaps slightly more efficient.</sup>

The following command moves the files into subdirectories named for their type *groups*, where a type group is formed by the first `,`-separated token of the full type description (e.g., the type group of `PDF document, version 1.5` is `PDF document`):

```
file * | while IFS=':' read -r file type; do 
 [[ -f $file && -r $file ]] || continue
 [[ $type =~ ^\ *([^,]+) ]] && typeGroup=${BASH_REMATCH[1]//\//-}
 mkdir -p "$typeGroup" && mv "$file" "$typeGroup/" 
done
```

- Files that cannot be read due to lack of permissions are quietly ignored.
- Furthermore, any `/` chars. in type-group names are replaced with `-`. (e.g., `a /usr/bin/python script text executable` becomes `a -usr-bin-python script text executable`), but there may be additional edge cases that need handling. <sup>Thanks again, l'L'l.</sup>

Comment: It's a shame they didn't include something between a MME type and the Human Readable format. I found there are likely too many corner cases to consider to reliably handle everything. I think covering the more common ones is likely the only reasonable approach; in light of that I think it works well...